# Sed: Proper Escaping for Special Characters

Tags: sed, special-characters

I'm trying to work up a `sed` command for the command below. I'm trying search for `v=window.location.search.match` in a file and replace it with `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Here is what I have so far:

```
sed -i.bak 's/v=window.location.search.match/\<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"\>\</script\>/d' myfile.txt
```

After running this I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 49: unknown option to `s'
```

I'm confused as to where I should be placing each `\` for escaping.

Comment: use this format: `s_A_B_` ; this command replace all `A` with `B`

Comment: Thank you, Babyy that seemed to have done it. I'm now just wondering what I do to replace the entire line that contained `v=window.location.search.match` instead of just that matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Babyy, if your expression contains `/` characters, then you can change `sed` separator to something that won't risk to be found in your input file, such as `|` or `_`

```
sed -i.bak 's|v=window.location.search.match|<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>|' myfile.txt
```

Now if you want to replace the entire line, the first part of your expression should match everything, from line start to its end:

```
sed -i.bak 's|^.*v=window.location.search.match.*$|<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>|' myfile.txt
```